# How to embed a JUnit Test Suite in another Suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have an old Junit3 TestSuite I am trying to upgrade. I see this in the setup...

suite.addTest(AllSubTests.suite());

What is the equivalent in Junit 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Suite class the same way you add other tests...

```
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
  AllSubTests.class
})
```